# Some keys on the keyboard aren't working

Tags: keyboard

I'm facing a certain issue here with my ubutu laptop. Just started it and some jeys eg (K,A,4 7,S ) and others arent responding yet they were working fine a while back.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.